# Delete lines between 2 patterns, but only if it has a specific string inbetween

Tags: text-processing, sed

Example, I have a file with the following contents:

```
eggs
bacon
cereal

eggs
bacon
cheese
cereal
```

Output:

```
eggs
bacon
cereal
```

In the example, I want to delete lines between the words `eggs` and `cereal`, but only if it contains `cheese` in between.

How could I do this using `sed`?

I have been asked to be more specific, so here is basically what I want to do, and I hope this makes it more clear:

```
WeaponData
{
    TextureData
    {
                "crosshair"
                {
                                "file"  "vgui/replay/thumbnails/"
                                "x"             "0"
                                "y"             "0"
                                "width"         "64"
                                "height"        "64"
                }
                "weapon"
                {
                                "file"          "sprites/bucket_bat_red"
                                "x"             "0"
                                "y"             "0"
                                "width"         "200"
                                "height"                "128"
                }
                "weapon_s"
                {       
                                "file"          "sprites/bucket_bat_blue"
                                "x"             "0"
                                "y"             "0"
                                "width"         "200"
                                "height"                "128"
                }

                "ammo"
                {
                                "file"          "sprites/a_icons1"
                                "x"             "55"
                                "height"    "15"
                }

                "crosshair"
                {
                    "file"      "sprites/crosshairs" <---
                    "x"     "32"
                    "y"     "32"
                    "width"     "32"
                    "height"    "32"
                }

                "autoaim"
                {
                    "file"      "sprites/crosshairs"
                    "x"     "0"
                    "y"     "48"
                    "width"     "24"
                    "height"    "24"
                }
    }
}
```

This is the command I tried:

```
sed '/"crosshair"/,/}/d' file.txt
```

That command just deletes from the very first `"crosshair"` to the very last `}`, regardless of whether it has the line `"sprites/crosshairs"` inbetween or not.

I only want to delete from `"crosshair"` to `}` if between the patterns, the string `"sprites/crosshairs"` is found.
However there are other blocks of code on the text file containing `"sprites/crosshairs"`.

Such as:

```
"autoaim"
{
        "file"      "sprites/crosshairs"
        "x"     "0"
        "y"     "48"
        "width"     "24"
        "height"    "24"
}
```

This cannot be removed. I DEEPLY apologize for not explaining this earlier, but I did not think it would be necessary.

don_crissti's suggestion works quite well which is `sed '/crosshair/,/\}/{H;/\}/!d;s/.*//;x;/sprites\/crosshairs/d;s/.//;}' infile`

The output is this, however:

> ```
>               ...
>               "autoaim"
>               {
>   }
> }
> ```

`"autoaim"` is partially deleted, but not completely, but as you can see the block containing `"sprites/crosshairs"` is removed, as I wanted to do, but `autoaim` still cannot be modified

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*"crosshair"/,/}/{H;/}/!d;s/.*//;x;/sprites\/crosshairs/d;s/.//;}' infile
```

How it works:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*"crosshair"/,/}/{         # in this range
H                                            # append each line to hold buffer
/}/!d                                        # delete it if not the end of range
s/.*//                                       # empty the pattern space
x                                            # exchanges buffers
/sprites\/crosshairs/d                       # delete pattern space if it matches
s/.//                                        # remove leading newline, autoprint
}' infile
```

This assumes lines matching `^[[:blank:]]*"crosshair"` are always followed by a block of lines enclosed in braces, just like in your example.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has gotten me the closest to the desired result, but there is still one last problem. The question has been edited for one last time.

Comment: It has been done.

Comment: The output is the same, with `autoaim` being partially deleted, but, I am new to this site, and your dedication to answering my question is amazing. Thank you so very much.

Comment: This did the job. Thank you again for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

if `perl` is okay, one can use paragraph mode (`-00` option) and use multi-line regex match

```
$ cat ip.txt 
eggs
bacon
cereal

eggs
bacon
cheese
cereal

$ perl -00 -ne 'print if !/^eggs.*cheese.*cereal$/ms' ip.txt 
eggs
bacon
cereal
```